# Calculate Date And Time Difference In Java

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have three database (SQLServer) fields:

1. startDate (Date)
2. endDate (Date)
3. Duration (text).

I am calculating date and time difference by using java following code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

      DateTimeUtils obj = new DateTimeUtils();
      SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = 
                new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss");

      try {

        Date date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse("10/10/2013 11:30:10");
        Date date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse("13/10/2013 20:55:55");

        obj.printDifference(date1, date2);

      } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

    }

public void printDifference(Date startDate, Date endDate){

        //milliseconds
        long different = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
        String diff = "";
        System.out.println("startDate : " + startDate);
        System.out.println("endDate : "+ endDate);
        System.out.println("different : " + different);


        diff = String.format("%d:%d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(different), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(different) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(different)));
```

And It returns “HH:MM” and updates the Duration field as String in my database. This works great.

Now there will be multiple duration, what I want to do is once I have Duration, I would like to do add up multiple duration and it should return totalDuration:

For Example: 
In my **table # 1** I have,

Id      |  Duration

1001    | 05:04

1001    | 12:19

1001    | 02:16

**Table # 2**

Id      | totalDuration

1001    |   19:39

**My Question is:** How do I convert HH:Mm to Date and add multiple records together to get totalDuration. Total duration should be text and return the same format “HH:MM

Comment: Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.

Comment: Why do you want to convert HH:mm to date? Do you want to store it as` Date` in database? If so, do not do it, as it does not represent a date technically. It is a duration.

Comment: What about time zone? Are these date-times all in UTC/GMT?

Comment: Your example date-times are 3 days apart, yet you only return hours and minutes?

Comment: If you are pulling values from a database stored as a date-time value, why does your example code parse strings?

Answer (score 1):

If you actually have date values for start and end in table 1 it would be a lot easier to use datediff and sum the values.

Comment: Agreed.  If you actually must cache the values, store it as a `BIGINT` count (of milliseconds or whatever); this will allow you do math on the values much easier.  If you want hours/minutes, format on display.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have all the values you worked out then just accumulate a long millisecond count as you go and use that.

If not then there are a few ways, the simplest is probably going to be:

```
String[] split = duration.split(":");
long duration = Long.parseLong(split[0])*60*60*1000 + Long.parseLong(split[1])*60*1000;
```

You can then loop through adding up all those durations, then at the end convert it back to a `String`.

Really you should store the millisecond count in your database and then convert it to text to display though.

Answer (score 0):

### Question Not Clear

Your question is not clear. (a) Question fails to address issue of time zones. Are these date-times all in UTC/GMT? (b) Your example dates seem to be 3 days apart, yet your code returns only hours and minutes.

### Joda-Time

Trying to roll your own date-time calculations usually leads to trouble and frustration. See if a good date-time library can help you, such as [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new java.time.* classes bundled with Java 8.

### ISO 8601 Duration

The international standard for date and time, [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), defines a way to work with what it calls [durations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations). Historically, the concept has also been called periods. A duration tracks the concept of elapsed time in terms of years, months, days, hours, and minutes.

A value is represented as a string in the format of `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`. The 'P' indicates the beginning of a duration (Period) string. A 'T' indicates the time portion. Each number precedes its element designator. For example, "P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S" represents a duration of "three years, six months, four days, twelve hours, thirty minutes, and five seconds".

Joda-Time is ISO 8601 savvy, offering the [Period class](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) to represent an ISO duration. A Period can be constructed by passing an ISO duration string. Likewise, the default `toString` implementation on Period outputs an ISO duration string. You could store that ISO duration string in your database. Joda-Time Period instances can be added together by calling the `plus` method.

### Example Code

Here's example code using Joda-Time 2.3 in Java 7. I sourced the two date-time strings from your question. To demonstrate addition, I add an extra 5 minutes.

Good practice dictates being explicit about time zones rather than rely on defaults. Here I use Paris, choosing so arbitrarily. You may well be using UTC/GMT (no time zone offset), in which case you may pass the pre-defined time zone `DateTimeZone.UTC`.

```
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

DateTimeZone timeZone_Paris = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ); // Or for UTC/GMT, use: DateTimeZone.UTC
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" ).withZone( timeZone_Paris );

DateTime start = formatter.parseDateTime( "10/10/2013 11:30:10" );
DateTime stop = formatter.parseDateTime( "13/10/2013 20:55:55" );
Period period = new Period( start, stop );

DateTime now = new DateTime( timeZone_Paris );
Period period2 = new Period( now , now.plusMinutes( 5 ));

Period total = period.plus( period2 );
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "start: " + start.toString() );
System.out.println( "stop: " + stop.toString() );
System.out.println( "period: " + period.toString() );
System.out.println();
System.out.println( "now: " + now.toString() );
System.out.println( "period2: " + period2.toString() );
System.out.println();
System.out.println( "total: " + total.toString() );
```

When run…

```
start: 2013-10-10T11:30:10.000+02:00
stop: 2013-10-13T20:55:55.000+02:00
period: P3DT9H25M45S

now: 2013-12-24T01:03:10.029+01:00
period2: PT5M

total: P3DT9H30M45S
```

Note how the `25M` increased to `30M`.

### Date-Time Strings

Tip: If you control those date-time strings as shown in your example code, your work will be easier if you switched to using the standard ISO 8601 format. For example: `2013-12-21T21:03:48+05:30` or `2013-12-21T21:03:48Z`.

Using the "dd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss" format is ambiguous. No reason to use that rather than the standard format. A bonus: The standard format gives a chronological order when sorting alphabetically.